# Enabling Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure Breaks Navigation

Tags: sharepoint, migration

I'm migrating from WSS 3.0 to MOSS 2007, below are the steps I took to migrate.

1. Backed up the content database of our WSS 3.0 site.
2. Restored the database on our MOSS 2007 database server
3. Create a new Web Application on our MOSS 2007 server and pointed the database to the newly restored database.

Everything works correctly on the new server.  I enabled **Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** and navigations stops working correctly.

Where it use to say **Home** it now says **/**.  When I clicked on a link to any sub sites the top navigations reduces down to one button that says **Error**.  Also any sub site navigation on the side bar reads **Error**.

When I disable **Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** everything goes back to the way it was.

Comment: I discussed this with a few people and we aren't aware of this issue. I'd be intereseted in getting some additional information and details. You can follow-up with me at Kevinrey@microsoftMicrosoft.com

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to enable this feature in a site collection that has **not** been created from a **Publishing template**, it will not work. You need to create a new site collection and migrate the content over.

The [SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) is a good tool that can help with any migration.

Comment: Alex is right... WSS 3.0 does not have any concept of the publishing infrastructure as it is a MOSS feature, so turning it on for sites that were created in WSS 3.0 is going to have unexpected results as you are experiencing.